# Встраивать Питон в программу написанный на языке Си

Tags: python, c

Написал на DEV C++ эту программу. Если компилировать ошибки типа такие: **[Linker Error] undefined reference to `_imp__Py_SetProgramName'**. Как комилировать? (Я совсем новичок)

```
#include "c:/Python26/include/Python.h"  
main(int argc, char **argv)  
{  
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  
Py_Initialize();  
PyRun_SimpleString("import time\n");  
PyRun_SimpleString("print time.localtime(time.time())\n");  
Py_Finalize();  
}
```

Comment: Как подключить python26.lib? Я уже читал как по командной строке подключить и компилировать этот код, но не мог понять. Может вы по другому объясните...

Comment: компилируете на gcc?        

если да то надо в командной строке пропишите -lpython26

вроде так, возможно понадобится полный путь указать

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну вроде как вы подключили тока хеадер от питона, но не подключили библиотеку с реализацией функций которые определены в хеадере.           
По этому он не может найти функции при линковке.

Найдите у себя в питне откуда подключаете хеадер .lib файл библиотеки.   
Что то типо Python2.7.lib если в виндовс или libpytрon2.7.a в линукс.    
И подключите к проекту.

UPD: нашел в сети, но не проверят, так как нету самого Dev-C 
откроешь dev там вверху будет сервис -> параметры компилятора и там во втором окошке пропишешь путь к .a и галочку не забудь поставить